# Java: Generate a random boolean array with exactly 'x' true - Algorithm

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, random, boolean

I'm trying to create an algorithm that can generate a boolean array with random booleans given that exactly 'x' amount of the booleans are true. I have solved the algorithm but was curious if there was a cleaner way of doing this.

Below is an example of my work. Two variables, songsToPlay and songsToDownload are randomly generated variables but in this scenario, i have set them to a fixed number 8 and 4, respective. Another important point to mention is that the first boolean value in the array must be true.

> Problem: I need to randomly generate an array of 8 true and false values, with exactly 4 
>   of the values being true.

```
Random ran = new Random();
    int songsToPlay = 8;
    int songsToDl = 4
    Boolean[] ranDownloads = new Boolean[songsToPlay];
    ranDownloads[0] = true;
    int counter = 1; //track how many are true, given the first one is always true.

    for(int i = 1; i < ranDownloads.length; i++) {
            if((songsToDl - counter) >= (ranDownloads.length - i)) {
                ranDownloads[i] = true;
                counter++;
            } else {
                if(counter == songsToDl) {
                    while (i < ranDownloads.length) {
                        ranDownloads[i++] = false;
                    }
                break;
                } else {
                ranDownloads[i] = ran.nextBoolean();
                if(ranDownloads[i] == true) {
                    counter++;                      
                }
                }
            }

    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I need to randomly generate an array of 8 true and false values, with exactly 4 of the values being true.

This is a variation of a card shuffling problem

```
List<Boolean> flags = new ArrayList<Boolean>();
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) flags.add(true);
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) flags.add(false);
Collections.shuffle(flags);
```

This completes in O(N) time and you can be sure you have the number of true/false you wanted.

Note: all solutions have an equal chance of occurring.  The problem with just changing the values until you get the total you want is it is hard to ensure you don't have a bias in the results you produce.

From the JavaDoc for [Collections.shuffle(List)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle%28java.util.List%29)

> Randomly permutes the specified list using a default source of randomness. All permutations occur with approximately equal likelihood.
>
> This implementation traverses the list backwards, from the last element up to the second, repeatedly swapping a randomly selected element into the "current position". Elements are randomly selected from the portion of the list that runs from the first element to the current position, inclusive.
>
> **This method runs in linear time.** If the specified list does not implement the RandomAccess interface and is large, this implementation dumps the specified list into an array before shuffling it, and dumps the shuffled array back into the list. This avoids the quadratic behavior that would result from shuffling a "sequential access" list in place.

Comment: @JensG Yes, I have added a reference.

Comment: Wow, what a difference with what I have written! Clearly shows I'm still a leaner in Java. Thanks very much for this. Is it possible to accept two answers? Someone posted something similar but yours has more details.

Comment: @user3501875 If you can't choose between answers, give the rep to the one with the least rep. ;)

Comment: @user3501875: You can still upvote the other answers.

Comment: Thanks, can't rep until I have 15 myself unfortunately. I'll accept this one for more information!

Answer (score 2):

Choose four of the array indexes randomly and set their content to true (and make sure that you don't use the same index twice).

Answer (score 1):

Given that you use an Object array (`Boolean` rather than `boolean`), just

1. fill the first `n` with `Boolean.TRUE` and the rest with
   `Boolean.FALSE`
2. do `Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(yourArray))`

And you're all set.

See: [`Collections.shuffle(list)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle%28java.util.List%29), [`Arrays.asList(array)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29)

Comment: Great minds ... I agree (as I answered the same, even added true, before false) but I think using a List here would be easier than using an array.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I agree, but I wanted to keep closer to the OPs version

Comment: I thought so, +1 the advantage of your approach as this involves a minimum of changes.

Answer (score 0):

Why not create a BitSet and randomly flip x bits to 1.

Sample code as requested:

```
BitSet bs = new BitSet(songCount);

Random random = new Random();
// x: target number of true values
for (int i = 0; bs.cardinality() < x; i++) {
    bs.set(random.nextInt() % songCount);
}
```

Comment: Any chance you would be able to provide some sample code? Thanks!

Comment: Follow the way for open hash table then. Just I hate creating too much objects :)